# Discrete Choice models in Greene

Tags: econometrics, textbooks

I am trying to reproduce the values in table 17.1 of Greene (Greene, Econometric Analysis, 8th Edition):

[image]

The density and distribution functions for Cloglog are: $$f(x) = \exp(x) \exp[-\exp(x)]$$ and $$F(x)=1-\exp[-\exp(x)]]$$ I am trying to figure what these are for the Gompertz model. Some references seem to use the name Gompertz for the Cloglog model. That makes some sense: the density can be rewritten as $f(x)=\exp(x-\exp(x))$ which is the Gompertz distribution according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_distribution.

A second question is about the partial effects for PSI. This is using imputed values for PSI. I had to think hard and long about the notation $\text{Prob}(\text{Grade}=1|{\bf{x}}_{(PSI)}, PSI=1)$. Is that standard notation?